# Format Date and Time As Per User's Locale Settings using C++ Libraries

Tags: c++, datetime, c++14, cross-platform, epoch

I want to extract date and time from an Epoch value and convert as per User's Locale Settings . There is already an existing solution using Windows API https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12568/Format-Date-and-Time-As-Per-User-s-Locale-Settings

I want same thing to be platform independent. (Mac / Windows / Linux) How can I achieve this? Are there any C/C++ libraries to do the same? I am using C++14.

Comment: In C, try `strftime` with "%x %X" format, after first calling `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` or `setlocale(LC_TIME, "")`. Empty string for locale means "use the locale from the OS".

Comment: In C++, similar code would go like this: `std::cout.imbue(std::locale("")); std::cout << std::put_time(my_time, "%x %X");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @IgorTandetnik in the comments, here is the sample code to do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
    // Epoch value (in seconds since January 1, 1970)
    std::time_t epochValue = std::time(nullptr);

    // Convert the epoch value to a struct tm representing local time
    std::tm* localTime = std::localtime(&epochValue);

    // Set locale settings for cout
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""));

    // Print the formatted date and time according to the user's locale settings
    std::cout << std::put_time(localTime, "%x %X") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```